# How to decrement the quantity in a specific row while clicking

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem in my code while clicking the selected row the quantity reset to 1

I want to decrement it by 1 and also when the quantity hits the minimum value the selected row will be removed.

BTW I'm using `AbstractTableModel` to manage my data.

```java
private void OrderListMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    OrderTableModel model = (OrderTableModel) OrderList.getModel();
    Order order = new Order();
    int row = OrderList.getSelectedRow();
    int currentqty = (int) (model.getValueAt(row, 2));
    order =  model.getOrderAt(row);
    for (int i=currentqty - 1; i>=1; i--){
        currentqty = i;
    }
    order.setQuanity(currentqty);
    model.update(order);
```

[image: screen capture]

Comment: You don't need a for loop to decrement quantity by 1, `currentqty = currentqty - 1;` will be enough

Comment: Rather than `MouseLIstener`, I think you should use [selection listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your click handler, you just need to decrement the value by one (instead of looping until it is 1) and if it hits the minimum we need to call a function to remove the row in the Model:

```
private void OrderListMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    OrderTableModel model = (OrderTableModel) OrderList.getModel();
    Order order = new Order();
    int row = OrderList.getSelectedRow();
    int currentqty = (int) (model.getValueAt(row, 2));
    
    order =  model.getOrderAt(row);
    // decrement current quantity by one
    currentqty--;
    // if current quantity has hit the minimum? - i assumed 0 would be the number where you want to remove the row
    if (currentqty <= 0) {
        model.removeRowAt(row);
    } else {
        order.setQuanity(currentqty);
        model.update(order);
    }
}
```

In your class OrderTableModel you have to add this function for the remove to work:

```
public void removeRowAt(int row) {
    filters.remove(row);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
}
```

As these are only code snippets I was not able to run & test the code, but it should work.